# Understanding Perl pointers to hashes in my script

Tags: perl, pointers, hash, reference, hashtable

So I know how the split is working, my question is how the pointer $p is working here. Does it have a different value for each iteration, and the value gets pushed on to the hash as an array? Is that how it will keep those values together when I need to extract them? I have over 100 lines of values I need to reference back to and I'm not sure how it will do that if $p is not changing with each iteration. Thanks!

```
else{
  my($site,$x,$y) = split /,/, $_; 
  my $p;
  $p->{site} = $site; 
  $p->{x} = $x; 
  $p->{y} = $y; 
  push @{$die_loc{$pattern}}, $p;
}
```

Comment: if this code is within a loop (`while()`, `for()` etc), then yes, it's a different value on each iteration. To be more specific, you declare it as a scalar value lexicalized inside of `else` as a simple scalar, then immediately turn it into a hash reference, to which you set three keys, each with a value. So after the loop, if you iterate over the `$die_loc{$pattern}` array reference, each element will have a hash reference with its own `site`, `x` and `y` keys, with their own values

Comment: What iteration? All I see in the code you've posted is an `else` branch by itself.

Comment: yes this is inside of a while loop to read a file. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that this is all in a loop where `$_` is assigned every time through.

You *declare* `my $p` every time so each gets its own memory location once it is assigned to. At that point it is *autovivified* into a hash reference, since that's how it is assigned. That reference is copied onto the array, so you will have them all.  You can get the memory address of a reference using `refaddr` from the core module [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html). Or, for that matter, just print `$p`.

What you have can be written as

```
my $p = { site => $site, x => $x, y => $y };

push @{$die_loc{$pattern}}}, $p;
```

So after all is said and done, the hash `%die_loc` will under key `$pattern` have an array reference, which has for elements the hash references with keys `site`, `x`, and `y`.

```
use feature 'say';

foreach my $hr (@{$die_loc{$pattern}}) {
    say "site: $hr->{site}, x: $hr->{x}, y: $hr->{y}"
}
```

This prints a line for each (presumed) iteration that you processed. But generally you don't want to type key names but rather use `keys` to print a hash, for example

```
foreach my $hr (@{$die_loc{$pattern}}) {
    say join ', ', map { "$_: $hr->{$_}" } sort keys %$hr;
}
```

where keys are also sorted for consistent prints. Or use a module, like `Data::Dump`.

Note that references are a little different from pointers.

There is only a code fragment posted so let me also say that you want  to *always* start with

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is much better written like this

```
else {
    my ( $site, $x, $y ) = split /,/;

    my %p = (
        site => $site,
        x    => $x,
        y    => $y,
    );

    push @{ $die_loc{$pattern} }, \%p;
}
```

or, perhaps better still

```
else {
    my %p;

    @p{qw/ site x y /} = split /,/;

    push @{ $die_loc{$pattern} }, \%p;
}
```